# How to run multiple SVN services

Tags: windows, svn, windows-services, administration

Having read [Setting up Subversion on Windows](https://blog.codinghorror.com/setting-up-subversion-on-windows/) I am trying to figure out how to run multiple SVN services on one machine.
When I create more then one service using

```
sc create svnP1 ... binpath= "svnserve.exe --service -r c:\svn\repositories\project1" 
sc create svnP2 ... binpath= "svnserve.exe --service -r c:\svn\repositories\project2"
```

as a template (actual commands truncated) both services listen on the same port and using 
svn://servername/project2 goes to project1

So how can I do this or am I going down the wrong track?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A bit tangential, but I just use [VisualSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/). It is free, *very* easy to setup ("next", "next"...), and comes with an MMC snap-in to do all the admin. This makes it a doddle to get working on multiple repositories, without having to add extra services each time.

(note; they charge for the client, but you can use **any** SVN client to talk to it; I like [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/), but whatever you like...)

Also - under the hood, it uses Apache to expose the data, providing both HTTPS for security, and allowing internet usage over firewall-friendly ports.

Finally, it even allows the choice of "regular" username/password pairs, or integration with your network (domain etc) credentials. Pretty slick.

Comment: you can use the SVN protocol over the internet, you just might find more issues with corporate firewalls.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure why you would need separate services. One service can handle multiple repositories.

I think what you want is:

```
sc create svn ... binpath= "svnserve.exe --service -r c:\svn\repositories"
```

And then to create project1 and project2 as separate repositories:

```
svnadmin create c:\svn\repositories\project1
svnadmin create c:\svn\repositories\project2
```

This will create two independent repositories that can be configures separately for users and hook scripts.

Comment: This is actually what I wanted to do.
I have accepted Marc's answer because it is what I ended up using.

Comment: I have a question: I did the exact same way you explained. However, when I access "svn://localhost:3690" I do not see the list of repos. Using "svn://localhost/project1:3690" works. (Consider my svn is running on port 3690). Is there anything else that needs to be done? so that I can see the list of repos when I access "svn://localhost:3690"

Comment: @Ashwinkumar: there is no repository browser in Subversion! In other words, there is nothing that shows you a list of repositories served by the server (with default Subversion, at least! It might be possible that other value added versions might have this).

Comment: Thanks @crashmstr. Now I have the information for my question. +1